# why do the domain on m_domainTable has "." in the beginning

Tags: c#, cookies

I try to add cookies to a CookieContainer.

```
Cookie cook1= new Cookie("aaaa", "1111", "/", "abc.com");
Cookie cook2= new Cookie("bbbb", "2222", "/", "abc.com");
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
cookieContainer.Add(cook1);
cookieContainer.Add(cook2);
```

However, I monitor the cookieContainer in debug mode. I found that the value in m_domainTable is [".abc.com"] but not ["abc.com"].
Why there is a "." in the beginning of the domain? and how to remove "."?

Comment: Are you talking about Winforms (as per your tag selection) or Webforms? Please clarify.

Comment: winforms.  Thank you.

Comment: This is more a cookie question rather than C# or Winforms specific hence marked as duplicate, the behaviour is as designed, seems the OP is more interested in *why*.